# 3D scene-graph library for Java?

Tags: java, 3d, scenegraph

I'm looking for a reliable 3D scenegraph API for Java with good documentation, an active community and a license that allows for commercial use.

I ruled out [com.sun.scenegraph](https://scenegraph.dev.java.net/) because it's GPL (and seemingly dead), Java3D because of [this](https://java3d.dev.java.net/servlets/NewsItemView?newsItemID=5689) post and JMonkeyEngine because of [this](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/jmeforum/index.php?topic=9247.0) post. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Xith3D](http://xith.org); it uses JOGL, not Java3D.

Comment: The problem with Xith3D is that it has no roadmap and hasn't had one for years now. There are no regular releases or any sort of API stability. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the Java3D post is that they are adding a new scene graph, not replacing their current one, in order to more effectively mesh with JavaFX, which is targeted at webapps. I've used Java3D in the past and liked it, so I would recommend trying to contact the devs and ask what their plans are with respect to whatever app you're building.

Comment: The problem with Java3D is that the API is horrible.  Everything is treated as this parent-child relationship and there are way too many steps and methods to get even the simplest thing done.  Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually like that in most almost-at-the-metal graphics libraries - one step up from, say, OpenGL, at scene graph level. The main reason is that the way the positioning of bodies in the world works, if you enforce the parent-child relationship, calculating the world orientation of children is much cheaper, among other reasons. This can sometimes even be done on the graphics card if you maintain this sort of API. Libraries at this level seem to "organize" rendering, not simplify it. Perhaps there's a better library now that this question is a few years old...

Answer (score 1):

There is also [jReality](http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/jreality/) it's BSD licensed, uses JOGL and looks pretty nice.

> Supports a variety of output forms: software-only rendering, OpenGL rendering, immersive virtual reality (as in CAVE’s) rendering; as well as file formats like Pixar’s RenderMan® and SVG

Comment: I just took a look. It seems no better than Xith3D in that there is no roadmap or official release schedule. I also noticed it was rather slow when I ran the demo applications.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (mid 2012) I would strongly suggest [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/engine/). It has a pretty good 3D [scenegraph capability](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3athe_scene_graph), suitable for use in applications such as 3D games.

It is fully open source, and also has a very active community and strong development roadmap - which is pretty important if you want to use in in the long run!

Comment: i tried jMonkeyEngine... I find it quite horrible! Its quite difficult to import models with texture!