# Is there a 3D scene graph implementation for libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using libgdx for some time now,  and I have been asking myself for weeks now, if there is any suitable scenegraph implementation for libgdx. I do not mean the scene2d classes. I mean some graph function for 3d games. I searched a bit and did not find any... 
Do you know any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no 3D scene. It might be added in the near future. However the new 3D api provides everything to load a 3D scene (see my [loading a scene with libgdx](http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/) tutorial). It is also possible to load scene physics if your like (see the bullet ImportTest). So practically for the actual rendering a Scene3D would only have to take care about frustum culling and multiple render passes (like shadow mapping). This can be as simple as an array of model instances or an entity system if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but it depends on what exactly you're looking for. See https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/scene3d

If you just want to optimize loading and share model resources when rendering, it looks like the new Libgdx 3D API (will be part of the 0.9.9 release, part of the current nightly builds) has some support for that: http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/#more-71

If you're just looking for something to organize your objects, there may be a generic Java scene graph library that you can adapt to Libgdx.  Try [3D scene-graph library for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555347/3d-scene-graph-library-for-java)

Comment: I already use the new api. I just want to create a visibility check and some performance optimisations so that my app runs on lower end devices than my own nexus megapower 4^^ . The first link is 2 years old, i think it's probably a dead project...

Comment: yea right its old. take a look at the new wiki: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Grapics3DQuickStart Also links back to the xoppa examples.